# Grails application, behind Apache, doesn't see/access manually set headers

Tags: apache, tomcat, grails, groovy

My Grails 3.0.9 application cannot see/access manually set headers in Apache's configuration.

The same configuration serves PHP just fine (ie. `$_SERVER['legalGivenNames']`)

Url being used: `http://localhost:9009/test?p=abc`

Setup: `WAMP_2.2:9009 <--> Grails3.0.9_Tomcat7:8080`

Apache configuration:

```
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
....
<IfModule headers_module>
    SetEnv legalGivenNames "Me"
</IfModule>
...
<VirtualHost *:9009>
    DocumentRoot "c:\wamp\www"

    ProxyPass /test http://localhost:8080/ retry=1 acquire=3000 timeout=600 Keepalive=On
    ProxyPassReverse /test http://localhost:8080/

</VirtualHost>
```

My class:

```
package my.intercept

import org.grails.web.util.WebUtils
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

class MyInterceptor {

    static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyInterceptor.class);

    MyInterceptor(){
        matchAll()
    }

    boolean before() {
        // get current request
        def req = WebUtils.retrieveGrailsWebRequest().getCurrentRequest()
        def sess = req.getSession()

        //doesn't work, returns null
        logger.debug("getAttribute(\"legalGivenNames\") "+req.getAttribute("legalGivenNames"))

        //doesn't work, returns null
        logger.debug("getHeader(\"legalGivenNames\") "+req.getHeader("legalGivenNames"))

        //works, returns list of headers, none from Apache
        Enumeration<String> headers = req.getHeaderNames()
        if(headers == null)
            logger.debug("headers: null")
        else{
            for(String s : headers)
                logger.debug("header: "+s)
        }

        //works
        logger.debug("getHeader(\"user-agent\"): "+req.getHeader("user-agent"))

        //works - ie. ?p=abc
        logger.debug("getParameter(\"p\"): "+req.getParameter("p"))

        //works, prints alphanumeric string
        logger.debug("sess.id : "+sess.id)

        true
    }

    boolean after() { true }

    void afterView() {
        // no-op
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
DEBUG my.intercept.MyInterceptor - getAttribute("legalGivenNames") null
DEBUG my.intercept.MyInterceptor - getHeader("legalGivenNames") null
DEBUG my.intercept.MyInterceptor - header: host
DEBUG my.intercept.MyInterceptor - header: user-agent
DEBUG my.intercept.MyInterceptor - header: accept
DEBUG my.intercept.MyInterceptor - header: accept-language
DEBUG my.intercept.MyInterceptor - header: accept-encoding
DEBUG my.intercept.MyInterceptor - header: cookie
DEBUG my.intercept.MyInterceptor - header: cache-control
DEBUG my.intercept.MyInterceptor - header: x-forwarded-for
DEBUG my.intercept.MyInterceptor - header: x-forwarded-host
DEBUG my.intercept.MyInterceptor - header: x-forwarded-server
DEBUG my.intercept.MyInterceptor - header: connection
DEBUG my.intercept.MyInterceptor - getHeader("user-agent"): Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0
DEBUG my.intercept.MyInterceptor - getParameter("p"): abc
DEBUG my.intercept.MyInterceptor - sess.id : BE7DD4380AED7DA61F838DB8E999D427
```

**Update #1**

I exported a WAR and deployed in Tomcat8. I reworked the Apache ReverseProxy and the headers weren't going through.

**Update #2**

I've also tried the following combinations from my Apache configuration:

```
RequestHeader set customheaderA "trololo"
Header add customheaderB "hahaha"
```

Neither shows up.

**Update #3**

Using `PHP` as comparison, it only sees headers set using `SetEnv`. It seems to ignore `RequestHeader` and `Header` Apache commands.

Comment: Apache docs says that it's env variable for CGI/SSI. Are you sure your grails app is CGI script or SSI page?

Comment: @igor-artamonov I have no idea. I did try other combinations of setting headers, without any success (see update #2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this morning, `RequestHeader set testHeader "value"` works. Wish it would have worked prior to having asked a bounty.

Answer (score 1):

SetEnv is useful if you are using AJP protocol to proxy requests to Tomcat. AJP protocol supports proxying of env.variables -> Servlet request attributes  separately from HTTP headers. Just note that you must follow [a naming convention](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html#env) ("AJP_*") for this feature to work with mod_proxy_ajp.

If you are proxying via HTTP, using request headers is your only option. (And you have already found [how to configure them](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html#requestheader)).